# NCU (npm-check-update) updating angular packages fails

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, updates, package.json

So trying to update everything to this day, i used the following commands:

```
  G:\Projects\salarkazazi> npm i -g npm-check-updates
```

this was the output:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain 
circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142      

changed 313 packages, and audited 314 packages in 41s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

then:

```
PS G:\Projects\salarkazazi> ncu -u
```

it showed 2 major updates and typescript minor version update:

```
Upgrading G:\Projects\salarkazazi\package.json
[====================] 25/25 100%

 @angular-devkit/build-angular       ~12.2.2  →  ~12.2.3     
 @angular/cli                        ~12.2.2  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/compiler-cli               ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @types/jasmine                       ~3.8.0  →   ~3.8.2
 @types/node                        ^12.11.1  →  ^16.7.6
 jasmine-core                         ~3.8.0  →   ~3.9.0
 karma                                ~6.3.0  →   ~6.3.4
 typescript                           ~4.3.5  →   ~4.4.2
 @angular/animations                 ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/common                     ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/compiler                   ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/core                       ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/forms                      ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/platform-browser           ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic   ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 @angular/router                     ~12.2.0  →  ~12.2.3
 rxjs                                 ~6.6.0  →   ~7.3.0
 tslib                                ^2.3.0  →   ^2.3.1

Run npm install to install new versions.
```

so when i try to install the updates i get the following error:

```
PS G:\Projects\salarkazazi> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: salarkazazi@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"~4.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=4.2.3 <4.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-30T08_03_27_428Z-debug.log
```

this is the log file:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'G:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Salar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.21.0
2 info using node@v14.17.5
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 11ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 11ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:G:\Projects\salarkazazi\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Salar\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 19ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 19ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 2ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 29ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 948ms
29 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
30 silly idealTree buildDeps
31 silly fetch manifest @angular/animations@~12.2.3
32 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fanimations 1255ms (cache revalidated)
33 silly fetch manifest @angular/core@~12.2.3
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 161ms (cache revalidated)
35 silly fetch manifest rxjs@~7.3.0
36 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs 161ms (cache revalidated)
37 silly fetch manifest zone.js@~0.11.4
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js 164ms (cache revalidated)
39 silly fetch manifest @angular/common@~12.2.3
40 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon 202ms (cache revalidated)
41 silly fetch manifest @angular/compiler@~12.2.3
42 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler 474ms (cache revalidated)
43 silly fetch manifest @angular/forms@~12.2.3
44 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms 306ms (cache revalidated)
45 silly fetch manifest @angular/platform-browser@~12.2.3
46 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser 175ms (cache revalidated)
47 silly fetch manifest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~12.2.3
48 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic 176ms (cache revalidated)
49 silly fetch manifest @angular/router@~12.2.3
50 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter 165ms (cache revalidated)
51 silly fetch manifest @angular-devkit/build-angular@~12.2.3
52 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular 165ms (cache revalidated)
53 silly fetch manifest @angular/compiler-cli@~12.2.3
54 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler-cli 182ms (cache revalidated)
55 silly fetch manifest typescript@~4.4.2
56 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 6818ms (cache updated)
57 silly fetch manifest typescript@>=4.2.3 <4.4
58 timing idealTree Completed in 11485ms
59 timing command:install Completed in 11507ms
60 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
60 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1274:25)
60 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1241:34)
60 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1226:23)
60 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:877:11)
60 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:206:7)
60 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
60 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:147:5)
60 verbose stack     at async Install.install (C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:150:5)
61 verbose cwd G:\Projects\salarkazazi
62 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
63 verbose argv "G:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Salar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
64 verbose node v14.17.5
65 verbose npm  v7.21.0
66 error code ERESOLVE
67 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
68 error
69 error While resolving: [1msalarkazazi[22m@[1m0.0.0[22m
69 error Found: [1mtypescript[22m@[1m4.4.2[22m[2m[22m
69 error [2mnode_modules/typescript[22m
69 error   [33mdev[39m [1mtypescript[22m@"[1m~4.4.2[22m" from the root project
69 error
69 error Could not resolve dependency:
69 error [35mpeer[39m [1mtypescript[22m@"[1m>=4.2.3 <4.4[22m" from [1m@angular/compiler-cli[22m@[1m12.2.3[22m[2m[22m
69 error [2mnode_modules/@angular/compiler-cli[22m
69 error   [33mdev[39m [1m@angular/compiler-cli[22m@"[1m~12.2.3[22m" from the root project
69 error   [35mpeer[39m [1m@angular/compiler-cli[22m@"[1m^12.0.0[22m" from [1m@angular-devkit/build-angular[22m@[1m12.2.3[22m[2m[22m
69 error   [2mnode_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular[22m
69 error     [33mdev[39m [1m@angular-devkit/build-angular[22m@"[1m~12.2.3[22m" from the root project
69 error
69 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
69 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
69 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
69 error
69 error See C:\Users\Salar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
70 verbose exit 1
```

Am i right to guess there is some sort of a problem with dependency tree mostly related to Typescript?

in my package-lock.json i have this where typescript is inside peer dependency with the version it yelled at me as an error :

```
"node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli": {
      "version": "12.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/compiler-cli/-/compiler-cli-12.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-n4X7nE7NEJm8QfKUkPgTXBqyF66FnLtFhjsTnqqSi9u1CdqpBLY7mJkWvQuYob4QfRoKoi2+UxNhoi26fvngCw==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
        "@babel/types": "^7.8.6",
        "canonical-path": "1.0.0",
        "chokidar": "^3.0.0",
        "convert-source-map": "^1.5.1",
        "dependency-graph": "^0.11.0",
        "magic-string": "^0.25.0",
        "minimist": "^1.2.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
        "semver": "^7.0.0",
        "source-map": "^0.6.1",
        "sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.8",
        "tslib": "^2.2.0",
        "yargs": "^17.0.0"
      },
      "bin": {
        "ivy-ngcc": "ngcc/main-ivy-ngcc.js",
        "ng-xi18n": "src/extract_i18n.js",
        "ngc": "src/main.js",
        "ngcc": "ngcc/main-ngcc.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler": "12.2.2",
        "typescript": ">=4.2.3 <4.4"
      }
    },
"node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular": {
      "version": "12.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit/build-angular/-/build-angular-12.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-/KBz8YlujmRZwWqk3fjV5S4IWKEfDE6Vhpr2uo1GC6KtdK7/tA9usvm3ZGAFMu3DXn3eJwe2StgUnegPg3gqxA==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@ampproject/remapping": "1.0.1",
        "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1202.2",
        "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.1202.2",
        "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "0.1202.2",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "12.2.2",
        "@babel/core": "7.14.8",
        "@babel/generator": "7.14.8",
        "@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure": "7.14.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions": "7.14.7",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "7.14.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.14.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.8",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.14.8",
        "@babel/template": "7.14.5",
        "@discoveryjs/json-ext": "0.5.3",
        "@jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader": "3.0.5",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "12.2.2",
        "ansi-colors": "4.1.1",
        "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
        "browserslist": "^4.9.1",
        "cacache": "15.2.0",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001032",
        "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.2.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "9.0.1",
        "core-js": "3.16.0",
        "critters": "0.0.10",
        "css-loader": "6.2.0",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "esbuild": "0.12.17",
        "find-cache-dir": "3.3.1",
        "glob": "7.1.7",
        "https-proxy-agent": "5.0.0",
        "inquirer": "8.1.2",
        "karma-source-map-support": "1.4.0",
        "less": "4.1.1",
        "less-loader": "10.0.1",
        "license-webpack-plugin": "2.3.20",
        "loader-utils": "2.0.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.1.0",
        "minimatch": "3.0.4",
        "open": "8.2.1",
        "ora": "5.4.1",
        "parse5-html-rewriting-stream": "6.0.1",
        "piscina": "3.1.0",
        "postcss": "8.3.6",
        "postcss-import": "14.0.2",
        "postcss-loader": "6.1.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.9",
        "resolve-url-loader": "4.0.0",
        "rxjs": "6.6.7",
        "sass": "1.36.0",
        "sass-loader": "12.1.0",
        "semver": "7.3.5",
        "source-map-loader": "3.0.0",
        "source-map-support": "0.5.19",
        "style-loader": "3.2.1",
        "stylus": "0.54.8",
        "stylus-loader": "6.1.0",
        "terser": "5.7.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4",
        "text-table": "0.2.0",
        "tree-kill": "1.2.2",
        "tslib": "2.3.0",
        "webpack": "5.50.0",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "5.0.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2",
        "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
        "webpack-subresource-integrity": "1.5.2"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0",
        "npm": "^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6",
        "yarn": ">= 1.13.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/localize": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/service-worker": "^12.0.0",
        "karma": "^6.3.0",
        "ng-packagr": "^12.0.0",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.0",
        "tslint": "^6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.2.3 || ~4.3.2"
      },
      "peerDependenciesMeta": {
        "@angular/localize": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "@angular/service-worker": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "karma": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "ng-packagr": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "protractor": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "tailwindcss": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "tslint": {
          "optional": true
        }
      }
    },
```

how could i solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Restart

1. `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12` to update to the latest 12.x version
2. `npm outdated`
3. upgrading your dependencies one by one to the wanted version as mentionned in `npm outdated` by typing `ng update [specific dependency]@[wanted version]`, commit those changes